# Titanium Backup installation error

Tags: installation, titanium-backup

I was using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en_IN) previously. It was working fine when I rooted my device before a month. But Because of some problem in my phone I again rooted my device, and now when I install this app, I'm getting error 504.

I tried so many things: 
I tried with different internet connection with high speed.
I cleared Google play cache/ services cache clear data etc. 
I reset app preferences.
I downloaded apk from apkmiror. 
I tried with signed testing APK.
I tried with the edit common files like change app name.

Comment: Need to find out what error 504 is. Get in touch with the developer.

Comment: I guess you're getting this error from the Playstore app? Then see: [Error 504 when downloading apps from Play Store?](/q/35062/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for quick reply, but I almost read all the post. Please give me another solution.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Can't install the app - this is the error. What should I do? Can you help me buddy?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't use the Playstore app anymore.

Comment: @Izzy O'oo Why Izzy?

Comment: I don't like to be tracked by them for everything (guess you've read they even track your location when you turn that off?) – so I kicked them off, installed a custom ROM without installing GApps, and feed most of my needs from F-Droid. Even network location works without that G-spyware (using microG). Playstore hides critical details (like not showing all permissions, not warning of trackers of which I found apps having about 20 of them included) – so that place doesn't look safe to me at all. F-Droid won't permit those trackers, and warns of risks. Much better a place IMHO.

Comment: @Izzy Okay. It seems like you're technically strong person. At least, for me find some solution.

Comment: If you have a computer available, you could try [Raccoon](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/) to download the APK and manually installing it (assuming Playstore is at fault). You could also use [Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) to install apps from Playstore directly, bypassing the Playstore app.

Comment: @Izzy ummm...But I already found the APK from google, so Play store won't come in our picture. But still apk is also unable to install. (Link: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/titanium-track/titanium-backup/titanium-backup-7-0-0-11-release/titanium-backup-7-0-0-android-apk-download/ )

Comment: My bad, missed the APKMirror part – sorry. How did you install it? Right on the device using some file explorer – or via `adb install`? In the latter case, you might get a more descriptive error message (not just a number). [Checking the logs](/tags/logging/info) might bring up some hints as well.